# Replacing Balkan characters with English c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, character, special-characters

does anyone have any experience with replacing Balkan characters like "ščćž" into "sccz" in words that i get for example "Konjic" instead of "Konjić".
I started with this code which replaces "ščćž" with "sccz" but i'm not sure how to implement the result to replacing the characters within the words. Any help is appreciated.

This is my code for the character replacement:

```
        string hrvatskaSlova = "žčćš";
        string razgradjenaSlova = hrvatskaSlova.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        char[] filtriran = razgradjenaSlova.Where(x => char.GetUnicodeCategory(x) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray();
        string novaSlova = new String(filtriran).ToLower();
```

Comment: Duplicate's title is about speed, but the underlying process is one for one replacement of characters which is what you want (building the mapping: which characters are replaced with what you'll need to define).

Comment: @Richard is right. You can use the replace method off the String class to replace the characters. You have to define which characters should be replaced by what characters.

Comment: Ahaa i see, thank you for the input, i shall refer myself to the existing post then.